Exporting Omnistudio Components
I have a few omnistudio components which I need to export from the current org and import into another org. If I import the omnistudio components do I need to export the related Integration Procedures & Dataraptors separately or is exporting the omnistudio components enough?

If you export an Omniscript for example that uses Integration Procedures, sub-omniscripts or any other related components, the export wizard will give you the option to also export these components.
You will be able to select/deselect which related components you want to export with the Omniscript.
When you then import it in another org, all the related components that you selected will be imported as well, which is quite nice in my opinion.
Good luck!

Thanks @Adriaan. Just tried it and it worked the way you mentioned!

@code234 glad to hear!

I don't have enough reputation to comment in previous answer, but I have to add that it is the better one, because IDX Workbench is pretty buggy and a Salesforce support agent told us that it is the recommended way to do it.
Datapacks (import from main omnistudio component list layout, export from omniscript or whatever component in omnistudio you want to do it) are THE BEST WAY to do it although it can be done.
Flexcard export example:

IP export example 1-2

IP export example 2-2

